# PHP creates an array by using one array keys for keys and another for its values

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like this:

```
(
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 212
    [4] => 45
    [5] => 10.00
)

Array
(
    [0] => 58
    [1] => 59
    [2] => 60
    [3] => 61
)
```

What I want is, just creates an array by using one array keys for keys and another for its values. My expecting array shoud be as follow:

```
(
    [1] => 58
    [2] => 59
    [4] => 60
    [5] => 61
)
```

I tried it with array_combine() and array_fill_keys(), But I coudn't get it to work. Hope somebody many help me out.

Comment: `array_combine(array_keys($a), array_values($b))`

Comment: If you tried and it didn't work, you have to show that code.

Answer (score -1):

As per @jspit comment, array_flip don't work if the keys_array has two or more identical values.

```
$keys_array = array(1=> 12,2=> 212,4=> 45,5=> '10.00');
$values_array = array(0=> 58,1=> 59,2=> 60,3=> 61);
$resultarray = array_keys( array_flip($keys_array), $values_array );
print_r($resultarray);
```

Sample output

```
Array
(
    [1] => 58
    [2] => 59
    [4] => 60
    [5] => 61
)
```

Comment: This don't work with array_flip if the keys_array has two or more identical values. Use array_keys as Iłya Bursov says in the comment.

Comment: I forgot about that, Thanks @jspit I update the Answer